# JS: difference between assignments

Tags: javascript

what is the difference between:

```
let {children: templateChildren}=job;
```

and

```
let templateChildren = job.children;
```

are they not exactly the same? (both assigning the children key value of job to templateChildren)

Comment: Yes, both are same

Comment: The first one is called [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.